# Professor ranking system

Tags: career-path, professorship

It is commonly accepted that professorship is the final rank of promotion in universities. I would like to study the possibility for promoting professors further. Is there any grading or ranking system for professors in universities?

Comment: Would you please specify the location? Different countries have different systems.

Comment: At my university, we now have Senior Professors and Distinguished Professors.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are some universities in the U.S. that have ways of promoting professors beyond the rank of "Professor". As you know, the U.S. system has a somewhat standard progression of Assistant Professor to Associate Professor to Professor.

Some universities add a fourth rank to this, often by the name Distinguished Professor. This rank is meant to apply to particularly special professors who continue to be highly productive and exceed job norms even after being promoted to Professor.

The other rank above Professor in the U.S. is related to named positions, often called named chairs. These are individual faculty positions that are funded by donations to the university (actually, funded by the interest). It takes a lot of money to create a named chair position, so they are relatively few in number. These positions are typically given permanently to one person, and then a new recipient is chosen when that person leaves the position. They are usually considered the most prestigious faculty positions in the U.S.  You can tell someone has one of these because the position usually has a name attached to it, e.g. Susan Q might be the "Joan Smith professor of chemistry". For example, see the [list of named positions](http://science.psu.edu/about/honors/endowed) in science at Penn State.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Distinguished/University/Institute professor positions and named chairs previously mentioned, some universities subdivide the individual ranks into steps.  For example, at Berkeley the rank of Professor is subdivided into steps 1-9.5, and above that you have "above scale" professors.

http://ofew.berkeley.edu/academic-ladder

Answer (score 1):

They can negotiate more income, a nicer office, more resources, less teaching, etc. However, the room for negotiation differs from country to country.

Sometimes moving on to dean or chancelor position is considered a promotion, but I would consider it a form of punishment. It just means you have to spent a lot more time on management, so less time (if any) is left for doing interesting stuff. On the other hand, promotion in other sectors often also involve such a switch towards more management tasks, so calling it a promotion is probably justified.